# Index strategy for dynamic filters in DocumentDB

Tags: aggregation-framework, aws-documentdb

I am confused when creating an effective index strategy.

I am using Amazon DocumentDB and have a collection with this structure:

```
[
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3",
    "field4": "value4",
    "field5": "value5",
    "dateField": "dateValue"
    /* Other fields */
  }
]
```

I want to apply filters to this coll and sort it by its date field but these filters are dynamic
The fields From `field 1` to `field 5` are ordered by its cardinality(highest to lowest) and all are optionals but as I said, always sorted by its date field.

My doubts are:

- Can DocumentDB use one single index for matching and sorting?
- The above point can be applied for aggregation?
- If not, what is the right way to manage it?

My current indexes are:

```
 db.coll.createIndex({ field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1, field4: 1, field5: 1 })
 db.coll.createIndex({ dateField: 1 })
```

As I know field1 is the mandatory but what if the others are not present?
For Example:

```
db.coll.find({ field1: value1, field4: value4 })
/* Or */
db.coll.find({ field1: value1, field4: value4, field5: value5 })
/* Or */
db.coll.find({ field1: value1, field2: value2, field5: value5 })
/* Or */
db.coll.find({ field1: value1, field2: value2, field3: value3 })
/* Also I'd like to filter by date */
db.coll.find({ dateField: dateRange, field1: value1, field2: value2, field3: value3 })
```

In aggregation, will this correctly use the index(es)?

```
db.coll.aggregate( [
   { $match: {  field1: value1, field2: value2, field5: value5 } },
   { $sort: { dateField: -1 } }
]);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: DocumentDB has a [different server implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html) from MongoDB so some features and behaviour will differ (including index usage). If you are looking for an answer specific to DocumentDB (or MongoDB), you should be explicit about the product you are using.

Comment: Among the functional differences of indexes I don't find clarification for my case, so I assume there is compatibility at this point. Anyways may you give your suggestion for this as you'd do it for MongoDB, please? For future reference @Stennie

Answer (score 1):

MongoBD can use one single index for matching and sorting.

If you are saying you are proposing creating a single index that is compound of 5 fields - that is not the correct index strategy unless your query will most often have all 5 values.

Based on your sample queries, an individual index of the 5 fields and the date field - will work better.  for a total of 6 indexes.

Comment: I understand, my doubt now is if I have a filter with `field2`, `field3` will both indexes be used to find and a third one for sorting?. Can I query by any combination of fields and then sort it with no problem?

Comment: I erred somewhat in first post - while a 5 field compound index I don't think is the right strategy - one would not need all 5 for it to work - one needs the leading fields in order left to right..... so you could have F1, F2 with nothing else...it would use the index but F1, F3 would not be able to use the index beyond the F1 range.... to answer your questions: yes your find/match queries if one multiple separate index will use those index, including the sort.  In fact that is exactly what you want.